# Dynamic select options pipes in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, html-select, angular2-pipe

I have a few select fields with many options each. I'd like to limit number of options displayed in some of them depending on options choosen in the others. For example, if I choose option A from the first select, in the second select only options A and B would be visible (whereas I normally have more options here).

An example select looks like this:

```
<label>
    <span class="label-text">Transactions</span>
    <select formControlName="transaction">
    <option [selected]="true">
          --Choose--
    </option>
    <option *ngFor="let transaction of transactionOptions"
            [value]="transaction">
            {{transaction}}
    </option>
    </select>
</label>
```

All the values for all the selects are put in individual arrays. I'm thinking about applying some pipes to dynamically filter the list of options but I have no idea what's the most appropriate way to do it in Angular4 (I'm new in this framework). Could anybody suggest me something?

Comment: Well, you have examples here : https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: I know how to write a pipe but I'm thinking about this certain example. Let's say I have 5 selects and 5 arrays with strings (options) inside. How could I make a list of one certain select dependable on the choice in the second. I'd like to use pipe for that.

Comment: Or I can use any other solution if is better.

Comment: Well, what did you try so far ? Providing code as answer isn't really the purpose here. Did you create a pipe on your own ? Does it work for 2 selects but not for 3 ?

Comment: I'm looking for a concept. Like 'create one pipe per each select, there should be additional functions limiting pipes regarding on various changes; or - work on arrays, dynamicaly push or remove elements from the options arrays, it would be better because of some reasons'. Writing code is the easiest part of this job.